# Does a reverse key index help if i use an incremental sequence to insert subsequent values

Tags: oracle, indexing

I understood the basic rationale for a reverse key index that it will reduce index contention. Now if I have 3 numbers in the index: 12345, 27999, 30632, i can see that if i reverse these numbers, the next number in the sequence won't always hit the same leaf block.

But if the numbers were like :12345,12346,12347, then the next numbers 12348,12349 (incremented by 1) would hit the same leaf block even if the index is reversed:
54321,64321,74321,84321,94321.

So how is the reverse index helping me? It was supposed to help particularly while using sequences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we're talking about a sequence-generated value, you can't look at 5 values and draw too many conclusions.  You need to think about the data that has already been inserted and the data that will be inserted in the future.

Assuming that your sequence started at 12345, the first 5 values would be inserted sequentially.  But then the sixth value will be 12350.  Reverse that and you get 05321 which would go to the far left of the index.  Then you'd generate 12351.  Reverse that to get 15321 and that's again toward the left-hand side of the index between the first value you generated (54321) and the most recent value (05321).  As the sequence generates new values, they'll go further to the right until everything resets every 10 numbers and you're inserting into the far left-hand side of the index again.